# DocusignApi - SignHere at bottom of the page

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to position a SignHere tab at the bottom of a page whose dimension is not known in advance ?

The only solution I've found so far is to add some custom code that :

- measures the page size
- uses a large SignHere tab offset based on the measured size

It would be great if either of these was possible :

- use negative offset in hopes that docusign interprets it as positive distance from the bottom
- use a small positive offset and fill in an additional property that specifies that offset is relative to the bottom

Comment: Is it not possible to use Anchor String (adding white text on white label at the bottom of the document) for placing SIgnHere tab on the document?

Comment: Unfortunately anchor string is not a solution because we are signing user-submitted files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uncommon to use a "signature page" as the place for the signer(s) to sign.

The language at the top of the signature page says that the signer has read/agreed with the prior pages.

You can also add an initials requirement via DocuSign for the customer submitted pages.

If you want to add a signature field to the bottom of each page then your idea sounds good.

Talk with your company's or organization's attorney to see if a signature page can be used as an alternative.

Comment: We know signing each page has no legal value but unfortunately our customers want to keep it to avoid any legal debate... I'll have to stick to the large positif offset. Thanks

Comment: I finally got it working. The hardest part was figuring out that even though `anchorOffset` is specified in `px`, `position` is specified in `pts` !